# Dying Light - Harran Ranger Bow - is it ever become obsolete in main campaign?

Tags: dying-light

I have just started playing campaign for the first time with every DLC enabled.
I quickly noticed that blueprint Harran Ranger Bow from DLC Harran Ranger Bundle is:

- Extremely cheap.
- Extremely overpowered in early stages (haven't played furhter), one-shots everything.
- Silent.

And on and on and on.

I think that this bow totally brakes intended experience, at least for the start of the main campaign.

The question is - does it still have unique properties till the very end of the main campaign? Does the process of playing using the bow and not using the bow differs significantly till the end of the campaign (i.e. are there other silent ways to pick enemies from afar in the main campaign (not in The Following))? Or does it just ease first 2-4 hours and then you are back on the standard track?

Same question for DLC Ultimate Survivor Bundle, which provides blueprints for weapons

- Buzz Killer
- Night Club
- The Constable
- The Lacerator.

I found posts over the net where those four are called becoming obsolete "very early in the campaign" (4-5 main mission). 
How is the bow compared to those four?

I am thinking on switching the bow off and starting from scratch, because I feel myself "omnipotent superdestroer" during first 1.5 hours with the bow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

haven't played Dying Light in a while but I remember that I played with my brother and he got the Bozac bow, who was very good even at the end of the game. And from what i've heard, the Harran bow is even more powerful (in term of damages and with the elemental arrows). If you wanna enjoy the game from the beggining (a.k.a hitting zombies with a wood stick) i'll recommend you not to use the bow (sry for my english).